# How much Truecolor Dye would I need to color a whole cloak for a medium creature?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

I'm wondering how much [Truecolor Dye](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/truecolor-dye) one would need to color an entire cloak to be worn by a medium creature.

The item description says that one vial is enough to coat a square foot of material—but that sounds like you're using it as paint, rather than as dye, which isn't really the same thing. (Nor do I know the standard square footage of a cloak in pathfinder, or whether we would have to do both sides or whether it would soak through).

I'm pretty sure there are no written rules on this (though please correct me if I'm wrong)—so how would you rule it if you were running a game with a PC who wanted to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question specifically asks what I would do as GM, not for a rules-as-written quote:  Ask your player to determine how many square feet their own cloak is.  They can describe it to you as they do, to give the entire table a solid visual of the style and shape of the cloak - they're spending the money to give their character a cosmetic effect, after all, they deserve a few minutes to put the spotlight on it and make sure everyone gets it.

When it comes to PC's appearance, it's virtually always best to rule in favor of the player.  The chances of using the cloak as an actual *detect evil* substitute are fairly low, so it's almost totally a cosmetic-only change.  After they estimate the square footage, round fractions up but go ahead and assume it soaks through.  Nothing in the rules says it does, but it *is* listed as a dye, not a paint, like you said, and there's just no point in charging a player twice as much to make his character look cool.

As far as a disguise:  It's true that this will cause people looking for the character to give differing descriptions, but that entirely depends on circumstance.  Most commoners are going to be neutral.  Many people who might hunt the character are also neutral (probably Lawful Neutral)- and orange probably stands out a bit in most crowds and locations.  Depending on the PC's actions and your story, though, they could attract Good or Evil stalkers.  The disguise becomes even worse in this situation:  bright gold or blood red will stand out a lot more in nearly every city (save maybe Cheliaxian cities) than a dull orange.  The Knowledge checks to identify the effects of truecolor dye are the two most common to dedicated trackers, as well (Paladins and Inquisitors might disagree, of course).  Neither a Paladin nor an Assassin would probably object to bringing a neutral spotter along to help discern the PC faster....  (the Paladin and the Assassin would likely not, however, work together, of course.)

Comment: It's not really a part of the answer, but has the player considered wearing a mostly blood-red, dull-orange, or bright-gold cloak and then drawing a *truecolor* emblem on it, making the emblem hidden to one of the three alignments?  I think that would be awesome.  "He's wearing an orange cloak with a red emblem on it" says the evil guard trying to get the character falsely strung up.  The other guards completely fail to notice an emblem at all or see only a gold emblem when they spot the PC.  The evil guard is gutted by the cult of Asmodeus for his failure.

Comment: I really like that idea. Now if only there were an equivalent dye for law/chaos, what fun we could have with mix and match fashion design.

Comment: @JeffThomas **Hidden cultist:** "Who wears lime green with blood red? Seriously?" **Inquisition:** "I think we've found our demon-worshipper..."

Comment: @GMJoe - Now there's a colorful way to get around Undetectable Alignment.

Comment: @Jeff I wish I could retract my upvote on your question as **pun**ishment for that pun.

Comment: @gatherer818 - I wish I could think of a suitable comeback that was also a pun. But instead, all I can think of are ways to elaborate on your cloak idea and use this to lead characters of certain alignments into traps with signage, etc.